# Keyup registers total amount of key-ups

Tags: javascript, mootools

## Problem

---

I am registering a keyup event that, when activated, shows a list of proposed subjects (using JSON).

My problem is that when a keyup is registered it somehow seems to remember the previous keyup(s) as well. This means that in stead of sending one request with JSON it sends multiple requests with JSON (depending on how many keyups have been registered). This is ofcourse very inefficient and I would like to settle with just 1 request per keyup.

## What have I tried

---

I have tried stepping through every action that is taken by the program. The problem occurs when I reach the second keyup statement (the first is to register a keyup in my template, the second one is a keyup in the class I am using which retrieves the value from the specified field). From this point on every keyup somehow gets "added" to the previous ones, resulting in for example:
3 previous keys were pressed -> (example) backspace gets pressed -> 4 keyups are now registered for the backspace keyup, all containing the same information.

I have tried setting up statements etc which check if previous events were the same as the current one, but that really didn't work out. The class works on different sites so I think the problem lays somewhere else, possibly the template (which contains another event that registers keyups, but completely removing that does not change anything) which was created be different programmers over time (and it's kind of a mess though I can't see anything that should create this weird behaviour).

## Relevant code

---

The template code:

```
$('subject_input').addEvent('keyup', function(event){
    var project_id = $('projectId').options[$('projectId').selectedIndex].get('value');

    if(project_id != "" && project_id != 0){ //Als er een project geselecteerd is 
        var elInput = $('subject_input');

        var gc = new GooCompleter('subject_input', {
            action: '/houroverview/ajax_subjects/'+project_id+'/',  // JSON source 
            param: 'search',            // Param string to send 
            listbox_offset: {x: 0, y: 0},   // Listbox offset for Y 
            typebox_offset: {x: 1, y: 1},
            delay: 100,                     // Request delay to 0.1 seconds 
        });
//Irrelevant code

                });
```

Class code keyup:

```
 // Retrieve suggestions on keyup
    this.field.addEvent('keyup', function(event) {
        console.log(event); //this shows the amount of keyups etc.
        //more code
    }.bind(this));
```

I should point out that I'm not all that great with JavaScript which means its taking me a lot of time to figure some stuff out. I still can't see anything in this code that should produce such weird behavior.

## Question

---

What is causing this weird behaviour and how can I get rid of it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, `GooCompleter` watches for keypresses by itself. You only need to initialize it once (e.g. in a `domready` event handler).

With your current implementation, a new instance of `GooCompleter` is created on every keyup, so after e.g. 10 keyups there are 10 `GooCompleter`s, each monitoring for keypresses and sending AJAX requests (so that a subsequent keyup will lead for 10 `GooCompleter`s to send 10 AJAX requests).

Comment: Haha, yeah I just figured this out myself it's working correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, according to your code, every keyup seems to make a new request. This is not weird behavior, just what your code does. The browser says that keyup happened every time keyup happens (any key is released on the keyboard) and your code sends a request as a reaction to each keyup.

You could ignore all but the last when they come back but you can also be more effective and not send any requests until the user stops typing for, say, 500 ms.

```
$('subject_input').addEvent('keyup', throttle( function(event) {
    //Once no keyup has happened for 500ms, this function is then called normally
}, 500 ));
```

Definition for throttle:

```
function throttle( fn, timeout ) {
    var timerid = 0;

    return function() {
        clearTimeout(timerid);

        var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
            ctx = this;

        timerid = setTimeout( function() {
            fn.apply( ctx, args );
        }, timeout );

    };
}
```

Comment: I knew saying "weird behavior" was going to bite me in the ass :P thanks, I will give this a try.

Comment: @Bono btw there was a bug in the code (used `timerId` instead of `timerid`), please use latest edit

Comment: Thanks, I used a different solution then you specified. But your solution did give me the idea to do so.